# Accessing a page only after a paypal payment has been made?

Tags: php, javascript, paypal

Can I create a page that is only viewable to people that have made a PayPal payment?

I am looking for users to make a payment before they can access a page, and if someone tried to view the page without a payment being made they would be redirected to an error page

Is this even a simple task?? If so, how would I go about setting this up and is there any tutorials online?

It's just a simple 2 page site I'm creating. Nothing complex....

I'm using the standard PayPal button just now but I'm not sure it's that simple

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="V6RE5BUJCBAPU">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is indeed to create a PayPal button. After the user has made the payment you can redirect him/her to a custom page which tells them they have successfully made the payment. You can let PayPal post the payment data to this page and you can verify this way that indeed the payment has been done successfully.

If so, you can set a SESSION or COOKIE variable and on your "target" page (the one they can only access after paying) you can verify if the SESSION or COOKIE has been set or not. If not, redirect them to the payment page.

**Example**

Make use of something like:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/index.php?payment=success" />
</form>
```

So after the payment has been done the user is redirected to **index.php?payment=success** and there you read the post from PayPal:

```
<?php
    $req = "cmd=_notify-synch";
    $tx_token = $_GET['tx'];
    $auth_token = "<your auth token here>";
    $req .= "&tx=$tx_token&at=$auth_token";

    //Post back to Paypal system to validate:
    $header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$fp) {
        //HTTP ERROR
    }
    else {
        fputs($fp, $header . $req);

        //Read body data:
        $res = '';
        $headerdone = false;
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $line = fgets($fp, 1024);
            if (strcmp($line, "\r\n") == 0) {
                $headerdone = true;
            }
            else{
                $res .= $line;
            }
        }

        //Parse the data:
        $lines = explode("\n", $res);
        $keyarray = array();
        if (strcmp($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0) {
            //Checks the payment_status is completed
            //check that txn_id has not been previously processed
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
                list($key, $val) = explode("=", $lines[$i]);
                $keyarray[urldecode($key)] = urldecode($val);
            }
        }

        //Process payment:
        $firstname = $keyarray['first_name'];
        $lastname = $keyarray['last_name'];

        //etc... you can either insert the payment data into your database for future reference
        //Or set up a COOKIE for the user to be able to download your file.
        //Or if your payment has been successful, redirect him to a "secret" page where the file is visible.
    }
?>
```

Comment: are there any tutorials online or examples i can see working?

im not 100% how to go about this

Comment: Yes there are plenty of tutorials about the example I gave to you on the PayPal website. I'll look for one.

Comment: @Gezzamondo: You can find a lot of code samples on the Paypal website here: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code

Comment: does the auth token come from when i create the paypal button?

Comment: what if someone tries to access the page without having paid, is there to redirect them somewhere?

Comment: @Gezzamondo: You find your auth token in your Paypal account settings. And someone can access the page without having paid, but then it does not hold a proper **tx_token**. The system makes a POST request towards Paypal holding your **auth token** and the transaction **tx_token**. Paypal verifies these two tokens and returns an array of data back to you. You can use this data to verify it the transaction was successful or not. (I did that at `if (strcmp($lines[0]. "SUCCESS") == 0) {` )

Comment: see in you code you have made a comment that said:

//Or if your payment has been successful, redirect him to a "secret" page where the file is visible.

how would i then redirect then from the code?  would i just add in
header('Location: newpage.php');  at the bottom of the code??

Comment: Jules, could i email u by any chance to discuss this paypal thing??  ive just read that ill have to change some settings in paypal to get this to work, but i dont want ALL payments made to my account redirected to this new page, getting slightly confused :S

Comment: Yes, redirecting is done by setting the header in PHP. If you don't want ALL payments be redirected to that page you can just verify what type of Payment was done in your "success" page. You could check this by reading the **item_name** or **item_number** variable that Paypal posts back to you. Read more about PDT here: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_html_paymentdatatransfer

Comment: but to set auto return and PDT in paypal i have to enter in a URL before i can save the settings, what would i put in there?

Comment: The URL you put there is the URL to the PHP file you are creating right now. Thus the file that verifies that the payment was done successfully and takes actions accordingly. But maybe it's better to read the link I gave you, Google some about PDT or IPN or find a way to chat with me, so we do not spam these comments. : )

Comment: hey Jules, can you email me at the above address please :)

Comment: @jules Does this still work?  I go under account settings in paypal, view the API section, hit view API signature but there is no auth token, just signature, api username, and api password.

Answer (score 0):

There'll be many solutions to your problem and one could be as follows ..

You can create a Paypal IPN handler page which updates your database when a payment is made. Then you can manually process all the payments and allow those users to view the restricted content. 
[I am assuming that you have some sort of user management system and are able to allow/disallow users to view some content.]

Just fyi, When you create a paypal button, you can also provide success page URI and failed/canceled page URI.

I hope this helps.